# Getting error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Control.Controls.get'

Tags: c#, webforms

Getting error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Control.Controls.get' when calling from Page_Load:
`System.Web.UI.Page.Controls.Add(new System.Web.UI.LiteralControl("Test Literal Control"));`

If I remove the `System.Web.UI` from Page it works.

What's wrong with it as I really need to use the full namespace?

Comment: Well which page do you expect that to refer to? Do you understand the difference between static members and instance members?

Comment: Apparently not, so how to I refer to the current page?

Comment: Well what context are you in? If you're in a member within a page, then just `this` is the current page... and you should be able to just use `Controls.Add(...)`. Basically you haven't given us enough context to help you at the moment.

Comment: Not sure how to give you the needed context but this is an .aspx content page that uses a masterpage and it works with just `Page.Controls.Add(new System.Web.UI.LiteralControl("Test Literal Control"));` but I really need the full namespace before `Page` because this will be used else where which is giving me the error `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Control.Controls.get'` which the exact same error as when I call it on the codebehind of the page, so I figured that if I solve it here it will work on the other side also.

Comment: [Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page(v=vs.110).aspx) class has a [Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.page(v=vs.110).aspx) property which is non static. But if you add `System.Web.UI` namespace to its prefix compiler sees `Page` as a class.

Comment: "because this will be used else where" - *where* will it be used, and how would that code know which page is relevant?

Comment: It will be used to dynamically compile c# and inject the results on the post content, so from my CMS editor I can have things like `<eval>2 + 2</eval>` -or- `<eval>DateTime.Now.Year - 1986</eval>` in the post, this is working very well using reflection.

Comment: Now I need to go one step further and add user controls the same way, so I'm trying to add a `Literal` and when that is working I'll scale it up to a full blown user control. But as I said the `Reflection` method if throwing the same error as when I try to inject a `Literal` on the `Page_Load` so I figured that fixing it on `Page_Load` also fixes it on the reflection method.

Comment: Can anyone create a test web project (web forms) with a master page and on Default.aspx.cs `Page_Load` add this: `System.Web.UI.Page.Controls.Add(new System.Web.UI.LiteralControl("Test Literal Control"));` see the error? How to fix this? Just `Page.Controls.Add(new System.Web.UI.LiteralControl("Test Literal Control"));` works but I need the full qualifying namespace before `Page`. Anyone?